# How to create pull/push queues in local google app engine environment

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore, task-queue

I need to start my google app engine project locally. It works normally on google server, but debugging becomes a pain, since deployment on each fix takes a lot of time. I've almost managed to start it locally, but I don't understand how to create queues, which are necessary. My steps:

1. `run dev_appserver.py app.yaml`, following [using local development server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-local-server) guide. All works fine except of queues:

   ```
   _, err := taskqueue.Add(u.Ctx(), task, queueName)
   exceptions.ThrowIfErr(true, "err_msg", err)
   ```

   Throws

   ```
   Panic! UserMessage: <err_msg>, Error: API error 1 (taskqueue: UNKNOWN_QUEUE),...
   ```
2. I can easily create queues on remote server (using [creating push](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/push/creating-push-queues) and [creating pull](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/pull/creating-pull-queues) guides):

   ```
   gcloud app deploy queue.yaml
   ```

   For `queue.yaml`:

   ```
   queue:
   - name: Pull-Data-Queue
     mode: pull

   - name: Push-Data-Queue
     mode: push
     rate: 1/s
   ```
3. I can open http://localhost:8000/datastore and see some created data.
4. I can open http://localhost:8000/taskqueue and see the only one default push queue. No tools to add new queues here.

Google guide says queues can't be created dynamically from code, only by yaml or xml. But how to create them in local environment. Is it even possible? `gcloud app deploy queue.yaml` works only for remote deployment as far as I understand.

Comment: If the `queue.yaml` file is side-by-side with your `app.yaml` file the development server *should* detect it automatically (at least it does for python). If it's not in that place move it (or symlink it) there.

Comment: It works now. Thank you!

Comment: @joker512 May I ask you to post the solution as an answer?

Comment: @GonçaloAlbino Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `queue.yaml` file is side-by-side with the `app.yaml` file the development server detects it automatically. It is possible to use symlink instead of copying. It fixed the problem.